# $\lim_{t \to 0}g(t)=10$ $\lim_{t \to 10}f(t)=100$ but $\lim_{t \to 0}f(g(t))$ does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

$\lim_{t \to 0}g(t)=10$ $\lim_{t \to 10}f(t)=100$ but $\lim_{t \to 0}f(g(t))$ does not exist.
Can anyone suggest two possible functions for f(t) and g(t)?
Both functions are defined on R

Comment: Not possible. ${}{}$

Comment: What if both do not have to be defined on R

Comment: Well, what are you really asking?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one example that I can think of.

1. Define $g$ to be: $g(x) := \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 10 &, \mbox{ if }x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ x + 10 &, \mbox{ if } x \notin \mathbb{Q} \end{array} \right.$

   I'll leave you to check that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x) = 10$.

   **Hint:** To prove this, you can use Squeeze's Theorem, and find a function $h$, such that $0 \le |g(x) - 10| \le h(x)$, and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} h(x) = 0$.
2. Define $f$ to be: $f(x) := \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 200 & , \mbox{ if } x = 10 \\ 100 &, \mbox{ if }x \neq 10 \end{array} \right.$

   Of course $\lim\limits_{x \to 10} f(x) = 100$. Do you see why?

But what's the limit of $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(g(x))$?

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing that out, fixed. ^^"

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.  Let $f(t)=100$ for all $t$ except $10$, and $f(10)=8$.  Let $g(t)=10 + t\sin(1/t)$ when $t\neq 0$, $g(0)=10$.